# Not able to autofilter the Column with multiple criteria using array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Autofilter a column with multiple criteria. Autofilter is only working with one data, but not with multiple data.

```
For lb1fil = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(lb1fil) = True Then
    strarray = Chr(34) & ListBox1.list(lb1fil) & Chr(34) & "," & strarray
End If
Next
Debug.Print Left(strarray, Len(strarray) - 1)
Worksheets("Result").Activate
Range("L4:L2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array(Left(strarray, 
Len(strarray) - 1)), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Please let me know if there is any alternative way or something I have missed.

I searched SO for solution but none of them are working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after RND, (Thanks to SO)

```
For lb1fil = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.Selected(lb1fil) = True Then
    'strarray = Chr(34) & ListBox1.list(lb1fil) & Chr(34) & ", " & strarray
    strarray = strarray & "," & ListBox1.list(lb1fil)
End If
Next
 Debug.Print Right(strarray, Len(strarray) - 1)
 strlen = Right(strarray, Len(strarray) - 1)
Debug.Print strlen

ary = Split(strlen, ",")

Worksheets("Result").Activate
Range("L4:L2000").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("L4").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("$L$4:$L$2000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I have added array using split, and it worked.

**PLease note the solution is from another question and the solution is not mine. So wanted to share that. Thanks**